# x86-64 CALL opcode + disassembly

Tags: assembly, binary-analysis, buffer-overflow, shellcode

Working a basic buffer overflow on a 64bit system and putting together some basic shellcode. The main program does a call to puts@plt. When I disassemble main in gdb, the opcodes show as:

```
e8 6b fe ff ff    0x555555554580 <puts@plt>
```

I looked at the [call instruction set reference](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_26.html) which says its a relative displacement from the next instruction. The next instruction is:

```
0x0000555555554715 b8 00 00 00 00 mov eax, 0x0
```

How is "6b fe ff ff" displaced from "0x555555554715" to get the puts@plt address?

I'm dropping my shellcode onto the stack, is it possible to call to puts@plt from there as a displacement from the next instruction? Or do I just need to setup the registers for a syscall?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

relative address can be forward or backward from end of current instruction
or start of next instruction

that **e8 00 00 00 00** will be call to the next immediate instruction
forward  can be    **e8 ( 00 00 00 00 .... 7f  ff ff ff )**
backward can be    **e8 ( ff ff ff ff .... 80 00 00 00 )**

so your immediate here is **0xfffffe6b**  that is == **-0x195**

negative numbers have their sign bit (31st bit ) set

```
0 & 0x80000000 == 0x80000000  will be False 
and
0xffffffff & 0x80000000 == 0x80000000  will be True

C:\>python -c "print((0xffffffff&0x80000000)==0x80000000);print((0x0&0x80000000)==0x80000000)"
True
False
```

so we can find out negative and positive numbers 
negative jumps backward 
positive jumps forward

positive 1 is 0 + 1
positive 2 is 0 + 2 and so on ......

negative 1 is 0x10000000 - 1
negative 2 is 0x10000000 - 2 and so on .......

```
>>> for i in range (1,20,1):
...     print (  "-%02d    ==    %x    +%02d    ==    %x" %  (i,( 0x10000000-i) ,i,( 0 + i )) )
...
-01    ==    fffffff    +01    ==    1
-02    ==    ffffffe    +02    ==    2
-03    ==    ffffffd    +03    ==    3
-04    ==    ffffffc    +04    ==    4
-05    ==    ffffffb    +05    ==    5
-06    ==    ffffffa    +06    ==    6
-07    ==    ffffff9    +07    ==    7
-08    ==    ffffff8    +08    ==    8
-09    ==    ffffff7    +09    ==    9
-10    ==    ffffff6    +10    ==    a
-11    ==    ffffff5    +11    ==    b
-12    ==    ffffff4    +12    ==    c
-13    ==    ffffff3    +13    ==    d
-14    ==    ffffff2    +14    ==    e
-15    ==    ffffff1    +15    ==    f
-16    ==    ffffff0    +16    ==    10
-17    ==    fffffef    +17    ==    11
-18    ==    fffffee    +18    ==    12
-19    ==    fffffed    +19    ==    13
```

so i subtract 0xfffffe6b from 0x100000000

```
C:\>python -c "print hex(0xfffffe6b - 0x100000000)"
-0x195L

C:\>python -c "print hex(0x0000555555554715 + (-0x195))"
0x555555554580L
```

demo in radare2

```
[0x00000000]> w \xe8\x00\x00\x00\x00 ; pd 1
            0x00000000      e800000000     call 5
[0x00000000]> w \xe8\x01\x00\x00\x00 ; pd 1
            0x00000000      e801000000     call 6
[0x00000000]> w \xe8\x02\x00\x00\x00 ; pd 1
            0x00000000      e802000000     call 7
[0x00000000]> w \xe8\x08\x00\x00\x00 ; pd 1
            0x00000000      e808000000     call 0xd
[0x00000000]> w \xe8\xff\xff\xff\xff ; pd 1
            0x00000000      e8ffffffff     call 4
[0x00000000]> w \xe8\xfe\xff\xff\xff ; pd 1
            0x00000000      e8feffffff     call 3
[0x00000000]> w \xe8\x6b\xff\xff\xff ; pd 1
            0x00000000      e86bffffff     call 0xffffff70
[0x00000000]> w \xe8\x6b\xfe\xff\xff ; pd 1
            0x00000000      e86bfeffff     call 0xfffffe70
[0x00000000]>
```

simulating an actual call opcodes

```
opening a random elf file 
:\>radare2 elfie

getting the address of sym.puts
[0x08048150]> ?v sym.puts
0x8048de0

calculating relative address for force writing a call to sym.puts
[0x08048150]> ?v sym.puts + 0x195 - 0x5
0x8048f70

seeking to target address
[0x08048150]> s sym.puts + 0x195 - 0x5

setting cache = true for writing to memory (radare2 opens in read only mode)
[0x08048f70]> e io.cache = true

checking the present disassembly
[0x08048f70]> pd 1
        `=< 0x08048f70      ebd7           jmp 0x8048f49
patching a call to sym.puts in place 

[0x08048f70]> w \xe8\x6b\xfe\xff\xff

checking disassembly again 

[0x08048f70]> pd 1
            0x08048f70      e86bfeffff     call sym.puts
```

Comment: I see how the -0x195 math works, but why the subtraction from 0x10000000? If forward can be 00 00 00 08 to ff ff ff ff and backward can be ff ff ff ff to 00 00 00 00, with the overlap, how do you know which direction the call is jumping?

Comment: added further details  to answer btw there is no overlap it was typo corrected the range